# Assigning pointer in method exits method?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn object orientated programming in c++ and can't understand why the following code wont print hi:

```
#include <iostream>

class test {
  double *x;
  double y = 5;

public:
  void printhi() {
    *x = y;
    std::cout << "hi";
  }
};

int main() {
  test a;
  a.printhi();

  return 1;
}
```

This code does not give me any output.
If I simply remove the pointer assignment, the `std::out<<"hi";` runs fine. Why? What does assigning a pointer there mean to the computer?

Comment: `x` doesn't point to anything, so reading/writing to `*x` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: What is `*x=y;` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member `x` does not have an initialiser. Therefore it will be default initialised if the class is default initialised. A default initialised pointer has an indeterminate value.

Attempting to  assign a non-existing object through a indeterminate pointer, or even reading that indeterminate value has undefined behaviour.

> What does assigning a pointer there mean to the computer?

You have not assigned a pointer. You have indirected through a pointer, and assigned the pointed object. Except no object is being pointed at because the pointer has an indeterminate value. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> If I simply remove the pointer assignment, the std::out<<"hi"; runs fine. Why?

If you remove the undefined behaviour, then the behaviour of this program will be what you would expect.

> I thought *x=y and x=&y are identical assignments

Not at all. First assigns through the pointer `x` and modifies the pointed object to have the same value as object `y`. The second modifies the pointer `x` to point to the object `y`.

`*x=y` is not an assignment of `x`. It is assignment of the object pointed by `x`.

> Yet x has an indeterminate value which can not be assigned

An indeterminate value can be assigned. Once assigned, the value will no longer be indeterminate. That is why `x=&y` would have well defined behaviour. It assigns the pointer.

That said, the usefulness of assigning an object pointer member to point to another member is dubious.

Comment: why is x=&y, better then? I thought *x=y and x=&y are identical assignments, yet one gives unidentified behaviour and the other doesn't. Is it because *x = y means make the thing x points at, equal to y. Yet x has an indeterminate value which can not be assigned. But if this is the case then x = &y is just assigning x to the memory address of y. Why is this assignment ok?

Comment: @V.Jain I've addressed this in my answer. Yes, it means that.

Comment: @V.Jain -- `*x = y` and `x = &y` are **completely different things**. The first stores a value at the location that `x` points to; the second sets the location that `x` points to.

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this is because I am trying to write code for the nelder mead algorithm which uses the simplex to find a minima of a function. To do this I am taking in a vector of points and in that vector I need to keep track of a specific point which has the highest output. I thought keeping a separate variable which points to the point with the highest value would be one way to do it.

Comment: @V.Jain I don't see how pointing to a member of same same object would be useful in that case.

Comment: It is kind of hard to explain over a comment, but I just want to know why is it advised not to do this kind of thing?

Comment: @V.Jain It is not advised to write code that doesn't make sense and has undefined behaviour. There's no sort of magic rule about that. It's like saying "don't crash your car into a wall". There's no sage wisdom as to _why_ you shouldn't crash your car into a wall, just don't do it unless you want to have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior.

```
*x=y;
```

You're dereferencing a pointer that hasn't been initialized. A pointer has to point to something before you can dereference it.

Answer (score -1):

> I have fixed this by changing *x=y to x=&y. Why does this work better? I thought these were 2 equivalent assignments.

They're two completely different things.

`x = &y` makes the pointer `x` point to the variable `y`. That's fine. That's great.

`*x = y` assigns the value of `y` to "whatever `x` points to". Except `x` points to nothing, because you never made it do that. You could possibly dynamically allocate a `double` for it to point to, then assign to that, but it's not clear that this is what you want to do.

Unfortunately, you did not tell us what you're trying to do, so we cannot say which is the right solution for you.

One possible outcome of undefined behaviour like you have in your code is that other, apparently sane code, suddenly "doesn't work". You're writing to "random" memory and you should get used to it not being a surprise that this causes weird sh!t to happen (like a `cout` not bearing fruit).